# Why after CONCAT are not variables equal in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select, concatenation

```
SET @date1 = 2015-04-06;
SET @date2 = "2015-04-06";

SELECT @date1 = @date2;
```

returns 0

```
SELECT "2015-04-06" = 2015-04-06;
```

returns 0

```
SELECT CONCAT('2015-04-06') = @date1;
```

returns 0

```
SELECT CONCAT('2015-04-06') = @date2;
```

returns 1 - Why? What I am doing wrong? And more obviously:

```
SELECT CONCAT('2015-04-06') = CONCAT('2015-04-06');
```

returns 1

Context: I'm trying to write function `is_bussiness_day(date)`, which uses `function getEaster(year)` posted by **Werner Kremer** on August 4 2009 3:06pm at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference i see is that date1 is given an Date and date2 a string.
Changing date2 to get a date, your concat = date2 is working.
To compare 2 Strings, one have to use `strcmp` function to do that.

```
STRCMP( CONCAT('2015-04-06'), CONCAT('2015-04-06'));
```

results to 0 (zero).
Hope, this helps...

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't put `2015-04-06` in quotes when you set `@date1`. So it's interpreting `2015-04-06` as an arithmetic expression, not a string. It's the same as:

```
SET @date1 = 2015 - 4 - 6;
```

which sets `@date1` to the number `2005`. Change to:

```
SET @date1 = '2015-04-06'
```

then

```
SELECET @date1 = @date2
```

will return `1`.